# Autostart program when windows boots (no user session)

Tags: windows, services

Is there any way to autorun an exe when windows boots up, but before user logs in? One of the options is register a windows service, however sometimes this is not possible. I'm looking for sth like a registry key (HKCU\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run).

Comment: As the most obvious use for this capability is to enable malware, it might help if you could explain your application in a little more detail.

Comment: HKLM instead of HKCU (assuming you have the rights to amend this key)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually turn pretty much any program to a Windows Service. See [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://iain.cx/src/nssm/).

Comment: Sorry, I can, however I cannot register windows service for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled Tasks allows you to create a task that runs when the computer starts.

You can either follow the instructions in the Microsoft KB to [create a scheduled task through the GUI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569), or you can run a command similar to this:

```
schtasks /create /tn MyTask /tr C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe /sc ONSTART /ru username /rp *
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a batch file to run the program and insert it into the standard startup scripts:

- Navigate to **Start -> Run** and type **gpedit.msc** then press Enter
- Under **Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings** open **Scripts(Startup/Shutdown)**
- Double-click "Startup" in right pane.
- Click **Add** and browse to your script and then click **OK**

Comment: How is this offensive?